# javascript setinterval doesn't fire synchronously at low intervals

Tags: javascript, setinterval, timing

Let's say there is a function `x()` which does some animation

If I loop through `x()`, say 100 times it takes < 1ms (on average / call) to execute it
However, if I do `setInterval(x, 100)` it takes on average of > 150ms to execute

Because of this quirkiness my animation is choppy.
(The reason for my for-loop test was to ensure `x()` isn't the bottleneck)

Are there any techniques / patterns to ensure my timer gets fired (at low intervals) synchronously and at the given interval and not at the mercy of the browser?

Update: Why does the following gives varying results for varying intervals
http://jsfiddle.net/zQQgH/7/

Update 2: Thanks to lincolnk, I have updated the code for anyone to check it out  http://jsfiddle.net/zQQgH/22/

Comment: `setInterval(x, 100)` means that `x` is going to be executed every 100ms. Since it takes less then 1ms to run, it's obviously going to be choppy...

Comment: You can play with this test app to see how well the browser stays with your requested interval: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/SGV82/

Comment: In your sample you aren't updating `prevTime` with the new time after calculating the last interval.

Comment: Basically even animators in the previous century knew that images have to change 25 times a second to have smooth animation. 1000ms / 25 = 40ms. This means that in order to create apparently smooth animation your interval function should fire ever 40ms or less. And of course your function has to execute faster than that interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't control this really perfect.

The reason for this is, that JavaScript is single threaded and works together with the browsers UI in one thread. This means that if you write setInterval(fn, 30) . You request the browser to call fn every 30ms. But the browser won't do this at this exact time. The browser will instead add your request to a queue.

You can find more information about this behavior [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

But I don't think, that this is the main problem, why your animation is choppy. **To get a smooth animation, you should use a timer between 16 and 35 ms. (Best animation time should be 16.6666667.)**

There is also the possibility to use [RequestAnimationFrame](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/05/03/better-javascript-animations-with-requestanimationframe/) (This blog post has also some extra informations about how to use setInterval/setTimeout for animations). Paul Irish has written a simple [polyfill for RequestAnimationFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/).

If you still have problems, simply post your animation script with working HTML/CSS. I can look into this.

Comment: The interval issue is a problem of IE. FF and chrome have better timers that can handle a resolution lower than 16ms.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `setTimeout` instead in your callback.

Comment: Agreed - setTimeout is almost always better than using setInterval.

Comment: why? If you're going to suggest an alternative, provide an argument why it's better.

Comment: @lincolnk: `setInterval` attempts use smart behavior to "catch up" with the timeframe, meaning it can skip certain intervals from time to time. `setTimeout`, on the other hand, will execute it regardless when it can get to it and does not attempt to skip intervals it may have missed. Typically, `setInterval`'s behavior is "good enough" for most situations, but in an animation scenario, `setTimeout` is *likely* to yield better results.

Comment: @lincolnk Pretty much the same reasoning as Reid. In my experience setInterval causes nothing but trouble unless you're using fairly long intervals (order of seconds).